# std::shared_future operator= thread safety/ atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std, future

**General question:** **Is std::shared_future::operator= atomic?**

For example

```
struct object {
    object() {
        sf = std::async(std::launch::async, &async_func).share(); 
    }
    void change(){
        sf = std::async(std::launch::async, &other_async_func).share();
    }
    void read(){
        while (true){ sf.get(); }
    }
    std::shared_future<int> sf;
};
```

**Question Part 1** Is it OK to call `std::shared_future::operator=` while the left, e.g. old `shared_future`, has not been waited on/*asynchronous provider* still running? Like in `object::change()`.

**Question Part 2** Is it OK to call `std::shared_future::operator=` while other *asynchronous return objects* / threads that are concurrent calling `std::shared_future.get()`? Like in `object::read()`?
**Edit:** Forget `object::read()`, I mean of course with their own `std::shared_future` but the same *shared state*.

After reading of C++11 draft [N3485](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) §30.6.7:12

> shared_future& operator=(shared_future&& rhs) noexcept; 
>   12 Effects:
>
> — releases any shared state (30.6.4);
>
> — move assigns the contents of rhs to *this

**Question Part 1** depends solely on *releasing a shared state*, e.g. after reading of §30.6.4, *destroying a shared state*, so I guess that means Part 1 **should be true**, but I'm not sure.

**Question Part 2 seems to be false**, because these are two steps and I neither know if the move part is atomic nor if what happens if the *shared state* is destroyed while other threads are in `shared_future::get()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are only notes in [futures.shared_future], but they're relevant:

> *[ Note:* Member functions of shared_future **do not synchronize with themselves**, but they synchronize with
>   the shared shared state. *—end note ]*
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> const R& shared_future::get() const;
> R& shared_future<R&>::get() const;
> void shared_future<void>::get() const;
> ```
>
> *Note:* access to a value object stored in the shared state is **unsynchronized**, so programmers should
>   apply only those operations on `R` that do not introduce a data race (1.10).

So calling `change()` is fine as long as nobody is calling `read()` or otherwise accessing `sf`.